# Class of output object differs as input data differs

Tags: r, sapply

I am trying to draw a variable number of samples for each of `n` attempts.  In this example `n = 8` because `length(n.obs) == 8`.  Once all of the samples have been drawn I want to combine them into a `matrix`.

Here is my first attempt:

```
set.seed(1234)
n.obs <- c(2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2)
my.samples <- sapply(1:8, function(x) sample(1:4, size=n.obs[x], prob=c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4), replace=TRUE))
my.samples
```

This approach produces a `list`.

```
class(my.samples)
#[1] "list"
```

I identify the number of columns needed in the output `matrix` using:

```
max.len <- max(sapply(my.samples, length))
max.len
#[1] 2
```

The output `matrix` can be created using:

```
 corrected.list <- lapply(my.samples, function(x) {c(x, rep(NA, max.len - length(x)))})
 output.matrix <- do.call(rbind, corrected.list)
 output.matrix[is.na(output.matrix)] <- 0
 output.matrix
 #     [,1] [,2]
 #[1,]    4    3 
 #[2,]    3    0
 #[3,]    3    2
 #[4,]    3    4
 #[5,]    4    3
 #[6,]    3    3
 #[7,]    3    4
 #[8,]    1    4
```

The above approach seems to work fine as along as `n.obs` includes multiple values and at least one `element` in `n.obs > 1`.  However, I want the code to be flexible enough to handle each of the following `n.obs`:

The above `sapply` statement returns a 2 x 8 `matrix` with the following `n.obs`.

```
set.seed(1234)
n.obs <- c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
```

The above `sapply` statement returns an `integer` with the following `n.obs`.

```
set.seed(3333)
n.obs <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
```

The above `sapply` statement returns a `list` with the following `n.obs`.

```
n.obs <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
```

Here are example desired results for each of the above three `n.obs`:

```
desired.output <- matrix(c(4, 3,
                           3, 3,
                           2, 3,
                           4, 4,
                           3, 3,
                           3, 3,
                           4, 1,
                           4, 2), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)

desired.output <- matrix(c(2,
                           3,
                           4,
                           2,
                           3,
                           4,
                           4,
                           1), ncol = 1, byrow = TRUE)

desired.output <- matrix(c(0,
                           0,
                           0,
                           0,
                           0,
                           0,
                           0,
                           0), ncol = 1, byrow = TRUE)
```

How can I generalize the code so that it always returns a `matrix` with eight rows regardless of the `n.obs` used as input?  One way would be to use a series of `if` statements to handle problematic cases, but I thought there might be a simpler and more efficient solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can write a function :

```
get_matrix <- function(n.obs) {

   nr <- length(n.obs)
   my.samples <- sapply(n.obs, function(x) 
                  sample(1:4, size=x, prob=c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4), replace=TRUE))
   max.len <- max(lengths(my.samples))
   mat <- matrix(c(sapply(my.samples, `[`, 1:max.len)), nrow = nr, byrow = TRUE)
   mat[is.na(mat)] <- 0
   mat
}
```

Checking output :

```
get_matrix(c(2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2))

#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    4
#[2,]    4    0
#[3,]    4    3
#[4,]    4    4
#[5,]    4    2
#[6,]    4    3
#[7,]    4    4
#[8,]    4    4

get_matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))

#     [,1]
#[1,]    4
#[2,]    4
#[3,]    3
#[4,]    4
#[5,]    2
#[6,]    4
#[7,]    1
#[8,]    4

get_matrix(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
#     [,1]
#[1,]    0
#[2,]    0
#[3,]    0
#[4,]    0
#[5,]    0
#[6,]    0
#[7,]    0
#[8,]    0
```

Comment: Very nice.  I never saw the `lengths` statement before.

Answer (score 1):

You could `Vectorize` the `sample` function on the `size=` argument.

```
samplev <- Vectorize(sample, "size", SIMPLIFY=F)
```

Wrap `samplev` into a function and assign maximal length using `length<-` in an `lapply`.

```
FUN <- function(n.obs, prob.=c(.1,.2,.3,.4)) {
  s <- do.call(rbind, lapply(
    samplev(1:4, size=n.obs, prob=prob., replace=TRUE), 
    `length<-`, max(n.obs)))
  if (!all(dim(s))) matrix(0, length(n.obs)) 
  else ({s[is.na(s)] <- 0; s})
}
```

*Results:*

```
set.seed(1234)
FUN(c(2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    4    3
# [2,]    3    0
# [3,]    3    2
# [4,]    3    4
# [5,]    4    3
# [6,]    3    3
# [7,]    3    4
# [8,]    1    4

FUN(c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    2    4
# [2,]    4    4
# [3,]    4    4
# [4,]    4    4
# [5,]    4    4
# [6,]    2    3
# [7,]    1    2
# [8,]    4    3
FUN(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
#      [,1]
# [1,]    4
# [2,]    4
# [3,]    3
# [4,]    4
# [5,]    2
# [6,]    4
# [7,]    4
# [8,]    1

FUN(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
#      [,1]
# [1,]    0
# [2,]    0
# [3,]    0
# [4,]    0
# [5,]    0
# [6,]    0
# [7,]    0
# [8,]    0

FUN(c(3, 4))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    2    3    3    0
# [2,]    4    3    4    3
```