# create sparse matrix from list

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

I wish to create a `sparse matrix` from a `list`.  I can create a typical `matrix` using the approach presented here:

[Class of output object differs as input data differs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61723298/class-of-output-object-differs-as-input-data-differs)

Below is a small reproducible example of the typical `matrix`.

```
set.seed(1234)

# determine number of observations in each sample
n.samples <- 20
max.obs   <- 10
obs.per.sample <- sample(0:max.obs, size = n.samples, prob = c(0.70,0.15,0.05,0.03,rep(0.01,7)), replace = TRUE)

# determine size of each observation in a sample
# here obs.size is a list
my.sizes   <- seq(10, 32, 2)
size.probs <- c(0.02,0.04,0.06,0.08,0.10,0.12,0.14,0.16,0.14,0.08,0.04,0.02)
obs.size   <- sapply(obs.per.sample, function(x) sample(my.sizes, size = x, prob = size.probs, replace=TRUE))

# create matrix of observation sizes in all samples
max.samples <- max(lengths(obs.size))
mat <- matrix(c(sapply(obs.size, `[`, 1:max.samples)), nrow = n.samples, byrow = TRUE)
mat[is.na(mat)] <- 0
mat
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    0    0    0
# [2,]    0    0    0
# [3,]    0    0    0
# [4,]    0    0    0
# [5,]   22   22    0
# [6,]    0    0    0
# [7,]    0    0    0
# [8,]    0    0    0
# [9,]    0    0    0
#[10,]    0    0    0
#[11,]    0    0    0
#[12,]    0    0    0
#[13,]    0    0    0
#[14,]   24   24   26
#[15,]    0    0    0
#[16,]   16    0    0
#[17,]    0    0    0
#[18,]    0    0    0
#[19,]    0    0    0
#[20,]    0    0    0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose `obs.size` is your list. And by sparse matrix you mean `sparseMatrix` from the package `Matrix`. You need to provide a i,j index and also the values for the non-zero entries.

For i, it is because the row index:

```
nonzero = sapply(obs.size,length)
i = rep(1:length(obs.size),nonzero)
i
[1]  5  5 14 14 14 16
```

j is the column index, my brain isn't functioning now so the code below might sux:

```
j = unlist(tapply(i,i,seq_along))
```

Then to make the matrix:

```
library(Matrix)
sparseMatrix(i=i,j=j,x=unlist(obs.size))
16 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
              
 [1,]  .  .  .
 [2,]  .  .  .
 [3,]  .  .  .
 [4,]  .  .  .
 [5,] 22 22  .
 [6,]  .  .  .
 [7,]  .  .  .
 [8,]  .  .  .
 [9,]  .  .  .
[10,]  .  .  .
[11,]  .  .  .
[12,]  .  .  .
[13,]  .  .  .
[14,] 24 24 26
[15,]  .  .  .
[16,] 16  .  .
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try the following base R option

```
l <- lengths(obs.size)
mat <- matrix(0,length(obs.size),max(l))
mat[cbind(rep(which(l>0),l[l>0]),sequence(l[l>0]))] <- unlist(obs.size)
```

where the indices of non-zero values are characterized by `cbind(rep(which(l>0),l[l>0]),sequence(l[l>0]))`, and you only need to assign the non-zero values, i.e., `unlist(obs.size)`, to those positions.

- Output

```
> mat
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    0    0    0
 [2,]    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    0    0
 [4,]    0    0    0
 [5,]   22   22    0
 [6,]    0    0    0
 [7,]    0    0    0
 [8,]    0    0    0
 [9,]    0    0    0
[10,]    0    0    0
[11,]    0    0    0
[12,]    0    0    0
[13,]    0    0    0
[14,]   24   24   26
[15,]    0    0    0
[16,]   16    0    0
[17,]    0    0    0
[18,]    0    0    0
[19,]    0    0    0
[20,]    0    0    0
```

---

If you need a sparse matrix, you may need help from `Matrix` package, e.g.,

```
library(Matrix)

l <- lengths(obs.size)
mat <- sparseMatrix(
  i = rep(which(l > 0), l[l > 0]),
  j = sequence(l[l > 0]),
  x = unlist(obs.size)
)
```

such that

```
> mat
16 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"

 [1,]  .  .  .
 [2,]  .  .  .
 [3,]  .  .  .
 [4,]  .  .  .
 [5,] 22 22  .
 [6,]  .  .  .
 [7,]  .  .  .
 [8,]  .  .  .
 [9,]  .  .  .
[10,]  .  .  .
[11,]  .  .  .
[12,]  .  .  .
[13,]  .  .  .
[14,] 24 24 26
[15,]  .  .  .
[16,] 16  .  .
```

Comment: Will this work if `n.samples <- 5000000` and `max.obs <- 500`?  I thought I needed a `sparse matrix` because the actual `matrix` is so huge and mostly contains zeroes.

Comment: I get an error message with your `sparseMatrix` code.

Comment: @MarkMiller Thanks for feedback. I missed something, but they are fixed now. See my update again